# How does bquote treat Unicode characters when using annotate R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, unicode, annotate

I was trying to include some Unicode characters as well as some expressions inside a plot. The Unicode character alone or in the axis works but when adding other elements does not show as expected. How can get the respective Unicode symbol?

```
ggplot()+
  annotate("text",x=1,y=1.3,
           label=bquote(C[1]~R^2*text[Psi]~"Currency \u20BF"),colour="blue",size=8)+
  annotate("text",x=1,y=1.2,
           label=bquote("Currency\u20BF"),colour="red",size=8)+
   annotate("text",x=1,y=1.1,
           label="Currency\u20BF",colour="red",size=8)+
  labs(x=("Currency \u20BF"))
```

[image]

Comment: When I try the code as-is, my default font family doesn't have a glyph for ₿, so it fails. But if I specify a font that does for `family`, all three work. You can also try typing/pasting the glyph itself instead of the unicode escaping for it—they should be equivalent, but may not always be.